# DBT CLI vars value doesn't get passed as string

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have a `var("run_date")` defined in the project YML to be yesterday as a date, using `dbt_date.yesterday()`

If I use this in SQL it works just fine. However, I'm using this setup to be able to override the value using the CLI.
But when I do something like

```
dbt run --select test_model --vars '{run_date: "2023-12-01"}'
```

it just gets passed as `2023-12-01` and the SQL fails.
I tried different ways of using ', " or without in the command, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using the following SQL to test this;

```
{% set run_date_dash = var("run_date") %}

SELECT REPLACE(SAFE_CAST( {{ run_date_dash }} as STRING), "-","") as test_date
```

Someone in another question fixed his problem by simply adding the '' in the sql, but that doesn't work here as by default the `run_date` is of type DATE

Any suggestions to fix this directly or should I build in some jinja condition to check if the variable is overruled or something?

UPDATE:
as a SELECT the code below seems to work, but might not be the nicest solution. My problem is that var("run_date") by default is dbt_date.yesterday(), which is just an SQL statement. This isn't executed within a macro if I'm correct? So using a macro wasn't a solution here.

However, trying to use this now in a WHERE statement seems to also be problematic, but that probably is a different question..

```
{% set run_date_dash = var("run_date" %}

{% if run_date_dash == dbt_date.yesterday() %}
  SELECT
    1 as test,
    REPLACE(CAST(
      cast(
        datetime_add(
          cast(
            cast(timestamp(datetime(current_timestamp(), 'Europe/Amsterdam')) as date) as datetime
          ),
          interval -1 day
        ) as date
      ) as STRING
    ), "-", "") as test_date
{% else %}
  SELECT
    1 as test,
    REPLACE(CAST('{{ run_date_dash }}' as STRING), "-", "") as test_date
{% endif %}
```

UPDATE2:
Managed to fix it using a macro that also can do other things to the date string if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things it's important to clarify:

- `dbt_date.yesterday()` is not SQL, it's a dbt jinja macro. It has to be called inside `{{ }}`. Kudos for using the cross-dialect macro.
- A `var` in `dbt_project.yml` of `dbt_date.yesterday()` will never evaluate even if you put it in `{{ }}` because the `var`s are only ever treated as strings. (I know it's annoying.)
- `var` and `env_var` are different variable types.
- Don't assume that `var("run_date")` is type date. It's in date format, but I bet it's type is string.

The "English" of what you're trying to do is "When I pass a `run_date` to dbt through the dbt CLI then use that date, else use yesterday's date."

The way to accomplish that is `{{ env_var('run_date', dbt_date.yesterday()) }} ::date`. The `::date` assumes you're in a SQL dialect that supports that casting syntax.

Note: If you're using dbt Cloud you'll want to name the variable `DBT_run_date` instead of `run_date`.

Comment: lot's of good insights here, thanks for that!
I didn't check the type explicitly, but the key point was that the behaviour was different in terms of using the defined var (as dbt_date.yesterday()) versus passing it along using --var '{}'
I fixed it using a Macro right now, I guess it is a better solution anyway as now I build in the check for usage of default versus passing in a variable as well as control of returning date as string with and without dashes as output. 

is run_date some reserved naming why you recommend using DBT_run_date instead?

Comment: You're welcome! 

Are you saying you have a macro checking `env_var` v. `var` existence to pick? Or something else?

No, dbt Cloud has a quirk where if you want to run a job sending an `env_var` it has to be prefixed with at least, "DBT", maybe "DBT_". I can't remember exactly, I actually always use "DBT_" whether I plan to run the job in dbt Cloud or not so I don't get stuck.

Comment: no, haven't encountered env_var before ;) 
I'm, checking if var is coming from the default project.yml (dbt_date.yesterday()) or if it is some other value (by CLI input)
good to know about the DBT_ prefix requirement for env_var